# How to Decide Whether To DataBind a Control or Not?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

What are some good guidelines to follow when deciding whether or not to databind a control (for example, bind a combobox to a List)?

Are there situations where you should always or never databind a combobox?

How do *you* decide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I measure it by how much manipulation of the data and its presentation I will be doing.

If it's light manipulation I'll just bind it, or at most do OnRowDataBound.

If I'm extensivelty maipulating the data, I'll spit it to a DataTable, manipulate it and Databind.

I always eventually databind() however.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if the data already exists in a datasource somewhere and that data has the potential to be kept up to date for the application's uses (through the application itself or by other systems/processes), I'll databind the control to that datasource.